# NGINX URL Masking

Tags: nginx

We have a server where nginx is installed, we have also configured PHP As FastCGI on the server. Everything is working fine except rewrite rule. Our requirement is to mask an URL

for eg:- if someone search in our website the URL which comes will be like http://example.com/search.php?searchword=$1 ($1=searched word) .  We need to display URL for our customers as http://example.com/$1.html.

We have set rewrite rule as rewrite ^/(([a-zA-Z_0-9]|-)+/?)$ /search.php?searchword=$1 break;

The URL is getting redirected however we get a file not found error each time. How can we mask the URL just as we do in Apache. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Equivalent Apache htaccess rules which we used are as follows

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ search.php?searchword=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ search.php?searchword=$1 [L]
```

It was working fine with Apache

Answer (score 1):

You should put this rewrite code to location / . I've tested it on my server.

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+).html/?$ /search.php?searchword=$1 last;
}
```